# Android Studio - Could not find tools.jar. Please check that X contains a valid JDK installation

Tags: java, android, macos, gradle, build

I am at my wits end trying to get this to work, and I'm not finding a solution. I just upgraded my Android Studio to Arctic Fox and I'm getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.
```

I am running on macOS BiGSur 11.2.3.

I opened terminal and ran `/usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk`

Which outputs:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
   1.8.301.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I tried editing `~/.zshrc` by adding various export lines such as:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

to which I get this error in the terminal after running `source ~/.zscrc`:

```
.zshrc:export:2: not valid in this context: Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

and tried this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

which just repeats the same Build failure.

I also tried adding various paths to the Gradle.properties file, such as one of the following:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Same Build failure for the first one, and `Value '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)` for the second one.

I did a search for tools.jar on my system, and nothing is found.

Also tried uninstalling Java and reinstalling it... nothing.

Please any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Finally found an answer. Apparently I only had the JRE installed, and not the JDK. Steps to fix:

1. Install [Java SE Development Kit 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
2. Re-run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk` to get the new path, which outputs:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.301.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_301 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home
```

3. Add the Java SE 8 path to android > gradle.properties: `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home`
4. Rebuild the app.

Hope this helps someone else after I spent 5 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Android Studio is so stupid that their upgrade breaks existing setup and doesn't even give useful error message

Comment: @hyouuu, It sounds like that's exactly what you needed. :) I agree that there are so many updates that it makes it difficult and discouraging to continue using.

Comment: I just tried this and still got the same error. Is there any other thing i need to change?

Comment: I was able to fix it after setting JAVA_HOME to the jdk path